# Prevent HTML Select Dropdown from expanding to longest string

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to prevent the Select element from expanding dynamically to the longest string?  My problem is I have a dynamically populated drop-down menu with a fixed width which displays fine, but when I expand the drop-down it ignores my fixed width and expands to the option element with the longest value as the pic below shows.

[image]

What I want to do is set the width to be fixed to prevent the above from occurring and add the value string to each option elements title attribute so longer strings will display on mouse hover.  I tried setting the width of the option elements, but it didn't work in Chrome or IE7-9.

My CSS and HTML for the select and option elements are as follows:

```
#myDropDown
{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 44px;
    font-size: Medium;
    width: 400px !important;
}

#myDropDown option
{
    width: 400px !important; 
}

<select id="myDropDown"></select>
```

UPDATE:

Thought the overflow property would do it.  Tried setting it in the select element and the option CSS, but neither worked in Chrome or IE.

UPDATE 2:

Ok, decided to cheat and just trim the strings that are longer than a certain fixed length and put the entire string in the title attribute of the option elements so users can see it on mouse over, I'll see if my client will accept that solution.  Thank you all for your input, I'll monitor this question today and tomorrow for any additional answers or suggestions.

Comment: what would you like the short version to display? a max string length and ellipsis? since you're dynamically populating, you could modify the strings as you're getting them...

Comment: Why would OP need a vertical scrollbar? He wants to limit the width (horizontal) of the option elements.

Comment: I could manipulate the strings dynamically as they're returned, but what if I don't or am not allowed to do that? I simply want the drop-down to remain the same size as the top-level select element.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is possible to do with pure CSS.

Also see this post here on SO: [Limit Initial width of select list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780843/limit-initial-width-of-select-list)

From that question it looks like you have two options.

1. as you already found out yourself you could 'truncate' the end of the string.
2. Use javascript to force it to a width.

Comment: Funny, the example they have for IE 6 & 7 is exactly the behavior I want.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a width to the options:

```
select{
    width:150px;
}
select option{
    width:120px;
    overflow:hidden;
}


<select>
<option>Lorem ipsum dolor</option>
<option>sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas eu diam risus, </option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had my select into a grid.  Thanks to the grid properties i can tell how width it should take between the row.

```
<Grid item xs={8}>
<div>
  <label> Some label </label>
  <Select className="comboStyle">
    ...
  </Select>
  </div>
</Grid>
```

And make sure that you set max-width to your "select" css

```
.comboStyle {
   max-width: 100%
}
```

In this way it can't grow from the width assigned from the grid container

BTW: I'm using Material UI Components, but pretty sure you can find a solution with pure html