# Jasperreports How to limit number of characters in input control multi-select box

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is there a way to limit the number of characters in an input control multi-select box? I would  like to allow some overflow but not an excessive amount. I'm using Jasper and iReport version 3.7.1

Comment: About what input control are you talking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options:

- modify the CSS for the input control (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780843/limit-initial-width-of-select-list) for options)
- modify your query so that it returns e.g. only the first 50 characters of the string

(see here [Jaspersoft community portal](http://community.jaspersoft.com//questions/802541/limiting-number-characters-input-control-multi-select-box))