# initial width of the select with opportunity for resizing

Tags: css

I have a select in a dialog box. The text for the options is long. When the page is loaded the select box should be rendered with static width (i.e. 50px), but when the dialog box will resize, this select should also resize. When I put `width:100%` initial size of select is adjusted to text from it. When I put `width:50px` the initial size is ok, but it isn't resized. An example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/34CPpJlZfgPHFa9o7VZf?p=preview).
The main problem is that this select is generated by Primefaces and I can't use this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3780943/3046524). 
I hope that exists pure CSS answer without using jQuery or JS.

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the following css change

```
.mySelect{
  min-width:50px;
  max-width:50px;
  width:auto;
}
```

Comment: In this case the initial width is also adjusted to the longest option text and not to 50px

Comment: You want the select width to set to a small width even this will hide some text of its options that are very long?

Comment: Or you want the select width to remain 50px all the time, regardless its option width?

Comment: When the page is loaded the select box should be rendered with static width (i.e. 50px), but when the dialog box will resize, this select should also resize. 
In my case this select also resizes the dialog box which is wrong behavior (when text is too long).

Comment: This dialog box is not a part of the code in jsfiddle?

Comment: Nope, the plunker is a simple example, but you can resize the window to test it.